# Error bd update

Tags: php, mysqli

tengo una clase db en php para actualizar un producto en la bd por una consulta preparada y me da problema al actualizar ya que paso los datos correctamente pero el pvp (es un double) se pasa como un string y al ejecutar la función me da ahí el error ya que la salida así lo muesta

[image: Imagen]

La pregunta es como puedo convertir ese string en double o si podéis darme otras opciones aquí os dejo la función, muchas gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí el cedido del índex y salida por pantalla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola. Por favor pon el código y el resultado como texto para poder ayudarte mejor. Pulsa en [edit] y mejora la pregunta. Gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!